# jQuery loop through JSON files and parse before continuing

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery script which parses some json files:

```
var jsonData = {};

$.when(
    $.getJSON('data/file1.json', function(data) {
        jsonData['file1'] = data;
    }),
    $.getJSON('data/file2.json', function(data) {
        jsonData['file2'] = data;
    })
).then(function() { 
    // do stuff
});
```

What I would like to do is make this more extensible by being able to loop through a list of  files.

I have tried this:

```
var jsonData = {};
var files = ['file1.json', 'file2.json'];

$.when(
    $.each(files, function( index, value ) {
        $.getJSON('data/' + value, function(data) {
            jsonData[value] = data;
        })
    })
).then(function() { 
    // do stuff
});
```

But then I seem to loose the asynchronous nature of the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var jsonData = {};
var files = ['file1.json', 'file2.json'];

// make array of promises

gets=$.map(
    files,
    function(f){ 
        return $.getJSON('data/'+f, function(data) {
            jsonData[f] = data;
        });
    }
);

$.when
    .apply(null,gets)
    .then(function() { 
        // do stuff
    }).fail(function() {
        // handle error
    });
```